# Why URL not working correctly when tried to turn image?

Tags: swift, url, firebase-realtime-database, imageview

I have question about firebase. I have image's URL in my database and I show them in collectionView cells but in this point I have some problem which is some image not loaded correctly their URLs are different but images are same. I tried lots of things but I can't solve it. My URLs starting with 'https' and App Transport Security Setting, Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES. So these are not solved my problem. Here my code which are firebase and adding this URL to imageViews. Please help me! Thanks!

```
func firebaseCon() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("cells")
    ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let dataCon = ItemCellImage()
            dataCon.itemImageName = dict["itemimagename"] as? String
            dataCon.itemTitleLabel = dict["itemimagelabel"] as? String
            //print(dataCon.itemImageName, dataCon.itemTitleLabel)
            self.itemler.append(dataCon)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here from data to image:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! itemsCell

    let dataGelen = itemler[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = dataGelen.itemTitleLabel

    if let cellDataImage = dataGelen.itemImageName {
            let url = URL(string: cellDataImage)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.itemsimageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.imageDeneme = UIImage(data: data!)!

                }
                }.resume()
    }
 return cell
 }
```

When I tried to change image url from firebase some of them working correctly and some of them show just previous image. Is there any way to show exactly correct image in every change?

Comment: Set `imageView` to nil or any placeHolderImage in `prepareForReuse()`  in your cell.

Comment: @SharadChauhan its seem working! Thank you so so much! If you add code to answer I will check correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of problem due to `Reusing` concept you can use `prepareForReuse()` function provide by `cells`.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
  yourImageView.image = nil //Or any placeholder image
}
```

This function is called when `OS is about to reuse your cell`, thus you can use it as a kind of reset to your cell appearance.